# Chain methods ability without force to new keyword using php

Tags: php, method-chaining

I'm working on a script that **MUST** to call like this:

```
$father = Father::firstName('Esaaro')->lastName('Ozaaraa')->age(42);

Person::firstName("Soobaasaa")->lastName( "Ozaaraa")->age(17)
  ->setFather( $father )-> toArray();
```

So we have two classes named `Person` and `Father`.

`firstName` method of two classes are `static` methods and other methods are `public`.

This is my file structure

```
<?php

class Person
{
    protected static $name;
    protected $lastName, $age, $father, $result;

    public static function firstName($name = null)
    {
        self::$name = $name;
    }

    public function lastName($lastName = null)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function age($age = null)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {

    }

    public function setFather(Father $father)
    {

    }
}


    /*
     * Father Class
     */

class Father
{
    protected static $name;
    protected $family, $age, $result;

    public static function firstName($name = null)
    {
        self::$name = $name;
    }

    public function lastName($lastName = null)
    {
        $this->family = $lastName;
    }

    public function age($age = null)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        ( (isset(static::$name) && static::$name !== null) ? $this->result['firsName'] = self::$name : '' );
        ( (isset($this->family) && $this->family !== null) ? $this->result['lastName'] = $this->family : '' );

        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

the above code is just structure and I just started to work on script. The file structure could not change because it's a challenge.

How should I manipulate my script that I can call methods like I mentioned before?

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"The file structure could not change"_? If we can't change the code, what are you expecting us to do here?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I mean this methods should remain but we can add more methods or manipulate the classes, even we can use traits if needed.

Comment: What is `Father::$family`? How is it populated?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want a static class that can be changed from anywhere in your program? All its properties can be changed from anywhere else in the program? Or you want someone to be able to change the first name of your mutable class, from anywhere in your program. So instantiated objects could have their firstname changed from elsewhere in the program? Please help define what you need. All of what you want is doable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really all you need is for the static `firstName` methods to create a new instance of the class and return it.

The other *setters* just need to return `$this` to provide what's referred to as a [*fluent interface*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).

If the only way to create an instance is via the static `firstName` method, you'll also want to add a private / protected constructor.

For example

```php
class Person
{
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $age;
    private $father;

    private function __construct(string $firstName) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public static function firstName(string $name) {
        return new Person($name);
    }

    public function lastName(string $lastName) {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function age(int $age) {
        $this->age = $age;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFather(Father $father) {
        $this->father = $father;
        return $this;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        // just an example
        return [
            'firstName' => $this->firstName,
            'lastName'  => $this->lastName,
            'age'       => $this->age,
            'father'    => $this->father->toArray(),
        ];
    }
}
```

I would strongly advise against keeping the `$name` property as static. You don't want to change one instance's `$name` and have it change all others. This is why I've changed it to `private $firstName` in my example above.

Comment: Might just be a matter of taste, but I would use `new self()` instead of `new Person()` to return an instance of the person object.

Comment: At this stage, I'm not seeing the point. AFAIK `new self()` just eases any refactoring burden

Answer (score 6):

I understand this is a challenge so you might have to use a specific class structure. But there is another way that this could be done:

```
class Father
{
    protected static $instance;

    protected $firstName = '';
    protected $lastName = '';

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->$name = array_shift($arguments);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (is_null(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }

        return static::$instance->$name(...$arguments);
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'firstName' => $this->firstName,
            'lastName' => $this->lastName
        ];
    }
}
```

In this version, you can call a function named after a protected variable either as static or not.  So, you could do `Father::firstName('dad')->lastName('saray')` or vice versa as `Father::lastName('saray')->firstName('dad')`.  For brevity, I left out the other methods like age.

As requested in a comment, here's what happens:

When you call `firstName()` or `lastName()` as static, the magic method `__callStatic()` is ran. If it detects there is no instance, it will create an instance, call that method and return the instance.  All future calls will then be handled by the magic method `__call()`.  That will set the property and return the same instance.  Now, that means you can call either `firstName()` or `lastName()` as static first, and then all subsequent calls will be non-static.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. This is good answer but would please be more descriptive and describe more and tell what if I have all functions and what would happen if I call methods in different order?

Comment: I updated it with more description of how this works. Hope this helped.

Comment: This is a more generic solution that will allow author to combine static and non-static methods. Although it won’t produce a desired outcome of instance of class is created, property is set, and then followed by static call. I believe the best option here would be to resort to either static or non-static calls for author to make his life easier. Adopt a standard and follow it throughout the code as is done by Eloquent.